# Instantiate Selenium webdriver in every class?

Tags: java, selenium

This is not specifically a Selenium issue but probably more my lack of Java knowledge. I am writing Selenium tests and trying to do them in an Object Oriented way. As a result every class I have instantiates the current webdriver in the constructor. This means that every single class has the same constructor. Is there a different approach I should use or a more 'Java-esque' solution?

```
public class Foo {
WebDriver driver;

    public Foo(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public static String getFoo(){
        String newFoo = "example";
    }
}
```

Then if I call Foo from another Class I have to pass the instantiated driver to it:

```
public class FooB {

    public static void doSomething(){
        Foo foo = new Foo(driver);
        foo.getFoo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be inheriting the base class to all other classes that will include `webdriver`. And, oh yea don't forget to use

```
PageFactory.initElements()
```

to initiate all the page elements. 
And, if I understood your question well then Page Object Model is the approach you should be taking. The implementation can different depending on the way you want. One of the best examples on how to implement this can be found [here](http://peternewhook.com/2010/09/automated-testing-pageobjects-webdriver/)